# Canvas goes blank whenever my if conditions are false

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas

I've run into an issue displaying data on my `canvas`.  I have multiple `if`, `else if` statements that I wanted evaluated to determine which text to display based on user input.

If I create the condition where a single `if` statement is true, the text that should be displayed does.  However when I add additional `else if` statements or if the single `if` statement evaluates as false, the `canvas` goes completely blank.  Examples below:

```
if((<?php echo empty($row['civ1']);?>) &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ2']);?>) &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ3']);?>) &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ4']);?>)){

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("", 705, 175);
}
```

This works only if it is the only condition evaluated and the condition evaluates as true.  If it evaluates as false, it causes my `canvas` to go blank.

Also if I add additional `else if` statements to handle other cases I want evaluated, the `canvas` always stays blank....

```
if((<?php echo empty($row['civ1']);?>) &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ2']);?>) &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ3']);?>) &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ4']);?>)){

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("", 705, 175);
}
else if((<?php echo !empty($row['civ1']);?>) &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ2']);?>) &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ3']);?>) &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ4']);?>)){

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("Civilian Goal:  <?php echo ($row['civ1']);?>", 705, 175);
}
else if((<?php echo !empty($row['civ1']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo !empty($row['civ2']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo !empty($row['civ3']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ4']);?>)){

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("Civilian Goal: <?php echo ($row['civ1']);?>", 650, 175);

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("<?php echo ($row['civ2']);?>", 760, 195);

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("<?php echo ($row['civ3']);?>", 760, 215);
}
```

Does this have something to do with how I use the `empty` statement in `php` or am I missing something else?  I use code similar to this in other places of my `canvas` and it works as expected.

[edit]

Here's the full set of javascript I use to evaluate if the user has input values or if they are blank and then what text I want displayed based on those inputs.

```
if((<?php echo empty($row['civ1']);?>) &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ2']);?>) &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ3']);?>) &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ4']);?>)){

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("", 705, 175);
}
else if((<?php echo !empty($row['civ1']);?>) &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ2']);?>) &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ3']);?>) &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ4']);?>)){

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("Civilian Goal:  <?php echo ($row['civ1']);?>", 705, 175);
}
else if((<?php echo !empty($row['civ1']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo !empty($row['civ2']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo !empty($row['civ3']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ4']);?>)){

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("Civilian Goal: <?php echo ($row['civ1']);?>", 650, 175);

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("<?php echo ($row['civ2']);?>", 760, 195);

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("<?php echo ($row['civ3']);?>", 760, 215);
}
else if((<?php echo !empty($row['civ1']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo !empty($row['civ2']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo !empty($row['civ3']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo !empty($row['civ4']);?>)){

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("Civilian Goal: <?php echo ($row['civ1']);?>", 650, 175);

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("<?php echo ($row['civ2']);?>", 760, 195);

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("<?php echo ($row['civ3']);?>", 760, 215);

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("<?php echo ($row['civ4']);?>", 760, 235);
}
else if((<?php echo empty($row['civ1']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo !empty($row['civ2']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo !empty($row['civ3']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo !empty($row['civ4']);?>)){

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("Civilian Goal: <?php echo ($row['civ2']);?>", 760, 175);

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("<?php echo ($row['civ3']);?>", 760, 195);

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("<?php echo ($row['civ4']);?>", 760, 215);
}
else if((<?php echo empty($row['civ1']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ2']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo !empty($row['civ3']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo !empty($row['civ4']);?>)){

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("Civilian Goal: <?php echo ($row['civ3']);?>", 760, 175);

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("<?php echo ($row['civ4']);?>", 760, 195);
}
else if((<?php echo empty($row['civ1']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ2']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ3']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo !empty($row['civ4']);?>)){

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("Civilian Goal: <?php echo ($row['civ4']);?>", 760, 175);
}
else if((<?php echo !empty($row['civ1']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ2']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo !empty($row['civ3']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo !empty($row['civ4']);?>)){

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("Civilian Goal: <?php echo ($row['civ1']);?>", 650, 175);

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("<?php echo ($row['civ3']);?>", 760, 195);

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("<?php echo ($row['civ4']);?>", 760, 215);
}
else if((<?php echo !empty($row['civ1']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo !empty($row['civ2']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ3']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo !empty($row['civ4']);?>)){

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("Civilian Goal: <?php echo ($row['civ1']);?>", 650, 175);

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("<?php echo ($row['civ2']);?>", 760, 195);

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("<?php echo ($row['civ4']);?>", 760, 215);
}
else if((<?php echo !empty($row['civ1']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ2']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ3']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo !empty($row['civ4']);?>)){

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("Civilian Goal: <?php echo ($row['civ1']);?>", 650, 175);

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("<?php echo ($row['civ4']);?>", 760, 195);
}
else if((<?php echo empty($row['civ1']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo !empty($row['civ2']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ3']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo !empty($row['civ4']);?>)){

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("Civilian Goal: <?php echo ($row['civ2']);?>", 650, 175);

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("<?php echo ($row['civ4']);?>", 760, 195);
}
else if(((<?php echo empty($row['civ1']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo !empty($row['civ2']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo !empty($row['civ3']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ4']);?>)){

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("Civilian Goal: <?php echo ($row['civ2']);?>", 650, 175);

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("<?php echo ($row['civ3']);?>", 760, 195);
}
else if((<?php echo empty($row['civ1']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ2']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo !empty($row['civ3']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo !empty($row['civ4']);?>)){

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("Civilian Goal: <?php echo ($row['civ3']);?>", 760, 175);

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("<?php echo ($row['civ4']);?>", 760, 195);
}
else if((<?php echo empty($row['civ1']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ2']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo !empty($row['civ3']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ4']);?>)){

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("Civilian Goal: <?php echo ($row['civ3']);?>", 760, 175);
} 
else if((<?php echo empty($row['civ1']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo !empty($row['civ2']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ3']);?>)  &&
(<?php echo empty($row['civ4']);?>)){

ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
ctx2.fillText("Civilian Goal: <?php echo ($row['civ2']);?>", 760, 175);
```

}

Comment: you're not treating the change of the context!

Comment: If it stays blank. Please take a look at the dev tools console if there is an error.

Comment: If the single one evaluates as false, surely its not drawing anything. Therefore would be blank lol (its an empty string also so still would be "blank") And the rest, can you paste the final javascript that gets created... maybe PHP is spitting out errors and ruining it.

Comment: Joushua K, my dev tool is notepad++

Comment: no. I meant the dev tools of your browser (Ctrl + Shift + K)

Comment: Epirocks, While I concur that specific text item would be blank, the canvas has other items to display as well.  Unfortunately the whole page goes blank whenever any of the if -  else if statements evaluate as false.

Comment: console says   SyntaxError: expected expression, got ')'

Comment: then you have to take a look at the given position in your code which raises the SyntaxError and find out what causes the problem. It's a syntax problem, nothing we can realy help. This is not the focus of SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is a liitle bit... ugly. Here is a solution to make it better and treat the change of the context in the right way using json. It's also better to debug.

```
var rowObj = <?=json_encode($row);?>;
// the following settings are the same for all conditions:
ctx2.font = "16px Arial";
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.textAlign = "left";
if(!rowObj.civ1 && !rowObj.civ2 && !rowObj.civ3 && !rowObj.civ4){
  ctx2.fillText("", 705, 175);
} else if(rowObj.civ1 && !rowObj.civ2 && !rowObj.civ3 && !rowObj.civ4){
  ctx2.fillText("Civilian Goal: "+rowObj.civ1, 705, 175);
} else if(rowObj.civ1 && rowObj.civ2 && rowObj.civ3 && !rowObj.civ4){
  ctx2.fillText("Civilian Goal: "+rowObj.civ1, 650, 175);
  ctx2.fillText(rowObj.civ2, 760, 195);
  ctx2.fillText(rowObj.civ3, 760, 215);
} else {
  alert('None of the conditions are met!');
}
```

Comment: Thanks...I give this a try.  Went down the "variable" route previously (not exactly like yours) and still got the same issue...I'm tracking your syntax and will send an update shortly.

Comment: Joshua K...this is working like a champ....had to fix one little bug in your code and we're good   row 9:  change +row.civ1 to +rowObj.civ1